# Finding Matching Templates and Getting Value Corresponding to It In Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I've looked into using filter, includes, some and other solutions but nothing seems to be suited to this.

This is the way the data I have appears -- and I need to get an array that only contains:

1. template id of each vehicle
2. the qty ([3] position value) of the vehicle

Thank you for any suggestions!

```
var vehicleTemplates = [
  ["230478", "uncommon", "Yellow Starship X2", "6"],
  ["230477", "uncommon", "Blue Starship X2", "6"],
  ["230476", "uncommon", "Green Starship X2", "6"],
  ["230473", "uncommon", "Red Starship X2", "6"],
  ["218034", "uncommon", "Purple Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["218033", "uncommon", "Yellow Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["218032", "uncommon", "Blue Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["218031", "uncommon", "Green Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["218029", "uncommon", "Red Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["218022", "uncommon", "Purple Truck T2", "6"],
  ["218021", "uncommon", "Yellow Truck T2", "6"],
  ["218019", "uncommon", "Blue Truck T2", "6"],
  ["218018", "uncommon", "Green Truck T2", "6"],
  ["218017", "uncommon", "Red Truck T2", "6"],
  ["208508", "common", "Standard Starship X2", "6"],
  ["208507", "common", "Standard Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["208506", "common", "Standard Truck T2", "6"]
];

var playerInventory = [
  ["115794", "uncommon", "Non Vehicle", "6"],
  ["230473", "uncommon", "Red Starship X2", "6"], 
  ["218034", "uncommon", "Purple Hovercraft W1", "4"],
  ["218033", "uncommon", "Yellow Hovercraft W1", "4"], 
  ["218022", "uncommon", "Non Vehicle", "4"]
];
```

I need to get an array that ONLY contains the vehicle id's that the player has in `playerInventory`

Then I would like to get the 3rd item in the array -- the qty of vehicles for that vehicle id.

Comment: please add the wanted result as data and your try.

Answer (score 0):

**Straight forward answer**

```
const multiArr = [
        ["21212", "uncommnon", "orange"],
        ["65565", "common", "blue"],
        ["87878", "uncommnon", "yellow"]
    ]

 const idArray = multiArr.map(ids => ids[0])
```

**Better solution**

Use a dictionary

This data structure may seem intuitive but it's a will promote messy decisions in dealing with this data structure.

What if the id *isn't* the first element? ( For Example )

This is a hard coded and non-scalable choice for data.

This is better choice

```
const dictionary = {
        "23232" : { rarity: "uncommon", color: "blue" },
        "65565" : { rarity: "common", color: "yellow" },
        "87878" : { rarity: "uncommon", color: "pink" }
}

dictionary["23232"]
```

Your search, insertion, deletion with ids will be o(1) and you get better access to data and get easily get a array of keys ( ids )

```
Object.keys(dictionary)
```